# AWS EC2 instance crashing whenever I run my python program

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, processor

I have a Python program for Data Collection from various sources, and then storing the data to my AWS Database using python.
I have developed the code using Python 3.8.

The code runs perfectly on my local machine, but when I try to run the code on my ec2 instance, the instance completely freezes and becomes inaccessible  and I have to reboot the instance to start it again.

My instance is a t2.micro.
I am guessing the reason for this issue might be the processing capability of the instance?
Is there any other angle that I am missing here?

Comment: When this happens, what is displayed for the "Instance state" and "Status check" columns in the AWS EC2 web console?

Comment: Note you may also be able to [view the EC2 system console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output) which may provide clues.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sometimes the status check fails (1/2) so then I have to reboot the instance to get it running again.

Comment: @AnonCoward I checked the logs but there is nothing related to this issue.
I also am tracking the CPU usage of the instance when i run the code, it shoots up to 80%, then 90% when the code is being executed

Answer (score -2):

its looks like someting about instance capacity try with t3 micro o medium

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?nc1=h_ls